# Web browser control wpf c# not loading page in windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, emulation

I am using a WebBrowser control embedded in a C# WPF .NET4 app. The html page that gets rendered have javascript event listeners and the page does not load in windows 10 machine, the same code works fine in windows 7 machine.

I have tried all the registry settings for Feature browser emulation and also added the meta tag in my page, but still can't get it work in windows 10 machine, can someone please suggest what can be done??

Comment: Is there any error when it doesn't work in Windows 10? Do you have [Internet Explorer 11 enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYHvr.png) in Windows feature? Do you have [script enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7MMd.png) in Internet Options-> Security-> Custom level?

Comment: No error and IE 11 is installed, script is enabled too

Comment: If so, I suggest that you can provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can run and 
 **reproduce the issue**. So that we can have a test and see how to help.